# How to include an internal reference in a code block?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my Sphinx .rst document I have a code block containing a tree view of the structure of my product using the UNIX `tree` command:

```
  |── parent
  |   |── child
  |       |── grandchild
```

It's in a code block so that Sphinx preserves the whitespaces.

I want readers to be able to click on each node to follow an [internal hyperlink](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#ref-role) to the part of the document that describes that node. However,  adding a `:ref:` inside the code block doesn't work (see below). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

This doesn't work:

```
.. _parent:

Parent
------
Blah blah

.. _child:

Child
-----
Blah blah

.. _grandchild:

Grandchild
----------
Blah blah
```

Then...:

```
|── :ref:`parent`
|   |── :ref:`child`
|       |── :ref:`grandchild`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`parsed-literal`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) directive:

```
.. parsed-literal:: 

   |── :ref:`parent`
   |   |── :ref:`child`
   |       |── :ref:`grandchild`
```

This works, but there are warning messages saying "WARNING: Inline substitution_reference start-string without end-string."

The vertical bars are interpreted as parts of [substitution references](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-references). The warnings go away with some escaping:

```
.. parsed-literal:: 

   \|── :ref:`parent`
   |   \|── :ref:`child`
   |       \|── :ref:`grandchild`
```

Answer (score 1):

`.. code-block::` is for literal code and does not get parsed except for syntax highlighting.

Instead you could use a CSS class `my-special-class` to apply styles to the tree, and write CSS styles similar to HTML's `<pre>` or `<code>`.  You will also need to escape `|` as `\|` because reST tries to parse `|` as a substitution.

reST:

```
.. rst-class:: my-special-class

\|── :ref:`parent`
\|   \|── :ref:`child`
\|       \|── :ref:`grandchild`
```

CSS:

```
.my-special-class {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```